# Qt Scaling Custom QGraphicsItem with unscaled text

Tags: c++, qt, text, qgraphicsitem

I'm trying to create customObject (rectangle and it inherit from QGraphicsItem) that will be painted on scene with ceratin text(stored in attribute), but when I scale it - i wish to keep same size of text. Here is my over. paint function:

```
    void CustomRectangle::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *options, QWidget *widget)
    {
        QColor currentColor = get_ColorByCurrentState();

        QRectF rect = boundingRect();
        QPen pen(currentColor, Own_LineWidith);

        painter->setPen(pen);
        painter->drawRect(rect);

        QRectF rect_text(rect.x(), rect.y(),100,100);
        painter->drawText(rect_text,this->getText() );
    }
```

and my two scaling functions:

```
    void CustomObject::scaleUp()
    {
        scale(ScaleFactor_X,ScaleFactor_Y);
    }

    void CustomObject::scaleDown()
    {
        scale(1/ScaleFactor_X,1/ScaleFactor_Y);
    }
```

But text still keep scaling along with rectangle.

**EDIT 1**
I tried adding it another way, i nfucntion that creates and adds my rectangle to scene (here - named "newObject"), but result is still the same.

```
    QGraphicsTextItem* GTI = new QGraphicsTextItem(newObject->toStringForScene(), newObject);
```

I'm beginign to think that I shoud create each text object as separeted object and save it different list. Ofcours, i would have to update it then, whenever it's object moved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this with QGraphicsTextItem's poitner as class's attribute.

```
QGraphicsTextItem* GTI;
```

I initialzie it in constructor:

```
GTI_Description = new  QGraphicsTextItem(this->toStringForScene());
```

and then I call function to updated it's X and Y:

```
void updateTextPosition()
{
    GTI->setX( this->x() );
    GTI->setY( this->y() );
}
```

and to add it to the scene:

```
addTextToScene(DragScene* _scene)
{
    updateDescriptionPosition();
    _scene->addItem(GTI_GTI);
    _scene->update();
}
```

Then i just call updateTextPosition() whenerver I change positions (in my mouseRelease event's handler).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
QGraphicsTextItem* gti = new QgraphicsTextItem("text");
gti->setFont(QFont("Arial", 18));

// this is important
gti->setFlag(QGraphicsTextItem::ItemIgnoresTransformations, true);

scene->addItem(gti);
```

The `QGraphicsItem::ItemIgnoresTransformations` flag prevents your graphics item to be scaled when you scale your view (*QGraphicsView*).

That means that you need a separated item for rendering text. But it can be a *child item* of your rectangle item.

Comment: That didnt work quite well as i expected. It ignores scaling its parent object up/down correctly, but also - ignores zooming out/in.

Comment: Yes, it ignores zoom in/out. I thought it's what you want. Sorry, I didn't understand your question correctly.